# How to prevent Delphi html editor breaking lines?

Tags: html, delphi, editor, html-editor

I am trying to edit some HTML code in Delphi Sydney IDE (checked also with Tokyo).
There are some mischiefs that make the IDE less than ideal for editing HTML.
One in particular drives me crazy: the editor breaks MOST of the lines in two. Like:

```
<li><a href="x.html">x</a></li>
```

results in:

```
      <li><a href="x.html">x
</a></li>
```

Any idea what to configure in "options" to make the IDE behave?

I guess, if one is ready to give up editing the file manually, and use the IDE editor only in WYSIWYG mode, then it is fine. But I am not. Maybe later I want to edit the file also manually.

---

Update: How to test it?
@Dsm - Save this StackOverflow page. Open the page in Delphi IDE. While in WYSIWYG mode, make one single change (put a blank space). Save the page. Compare the original page with the newly saved page in the BeyondCompare diff tool. The diff tool will be all red because the two files are now totally different (247 differences it says).

---

Update:
**Forget about it!** The so-called "html editor" is beyond useless. NOTHING works. It is plagued with bugs all over!
I spent 40 minutes to bring to date an old HTML page. Then I clicked another tab. When I returned to that page, all the changes were gone. Yes, every-time you switch away from an HTML page, the edits are lost.
Many things are just sloppy in Delphi IDE. This one is beyond sloppy!

@RemyLebeau - I apologize! You were right. This is NOT an HTML editor.

Comment: Maybe use an editor designed for the task at hand......

Comment: If you stay in the source view, it won't change what you wrote.

Comment: The IDE's code editor is not an HTML editor.  Use a more appropriate tool to edit HTML.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - So, I guess you wanted to say "Delphi's IDE *wants* to be an HTML editor, but fails because [enter reasons here]". The truth is that they did put a HTML code editor and also an HTML WYSIWYG editor in there. Is there. Right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Well, I paid some money to buy the Sydney license. I was hopping to be able to make use of its HTML "editor" (which to be honest is almost decent), so I won't have to pay for the also expensive Dreamweaver!

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience "*So, I guess you wanted to say ...*" - I said exactly what I wanted to say.

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience asking for tool recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Then I guess you are wrong. THERE IS a html editor in Delphi. I can send screenshots.

Comment: I tried creating a html file (File|New|Other|Webe Pages|HTML Page) and adding your line. There were no breaks, there. I am using Delphi 10.2. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dsm - Can be reproduced easily. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like Delphi editor to automatically adds new code indents then you should disable this in Delphi options.

You can do this by opening Delphi options through `Tools->Options` menu, and then move to `User Interface->Editor Options->Source Options`

Here you can change Source file type to HTML so you can make changes that affect only HTML files opened in Delphi editor.

[image: IDE Editor Source Options]

Comment: Actually, the settings in Source Options apply to all "source file type". It is quite easy to test it for yourself. Just change the first checkbox then switch from "HTML" to "Delphi" and that checkbox will remember the value you set for "HTML". Probably yet another bug in the IDE.

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience Uncheck the first checkbox while having HTML selected and then save. Once you open the settings again you will see that while having Default source file type the checkmark will still be checked but once you switch to HTML the checkmark will no longer be checked.

Comment: Anyway, this does not answer the question. Can you please clearly specify which of those settings will prevent the IDE from breaking lines in two? Because I could not find it